# How to limit the character movements to a delimited area

Tags: algorithm, character, scene, bounding-boxes, layers

Consider the below images get from the **Final Fantasy VII** and **Alone In The Dark** games:
[image]

[image]

I assume that the above scenes are composed by a set of layers composing the background image (allowing thus the character to be masked if required and so giving an illusion of deep), and a 3D character which is, as some other characters or special items, the only 3D rendering composing the scene. If this assumption is true, then how to code a such scene, in the point of view of the animation and drawing, is pretty clear for me.

What is less clear, on the other hand, is that, in these games, the player may move only in the delimited red area, and not outside. I cannot figure out how to develop a such behavior.

So my questions are:

- What is the name of the algorithm which limits the movement of the characters inside the red area
- How to approach the design and the tools required to develop a such functionality
- How to develop a such algorithm (in c++ if possible)

Any help or info about these points would be welcome.

Comment: Asking how a specific game implemented a specific feature is not considered on-topic ([link to reasons why](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1063/33287)). Rather than focusing on how this problem has been solved in *past games*, it would be preferable to edit to focus on how to solve this problem in the context of *your game/project*. Doing so will solicit answers tailored to your needs.

Comment: @Pikalek I understand your remark but I need to start from somewhere, and I even don't know how a such algorithm is called. But as an idea, one would be to place my layouts composing the background on several z positions, and an inclined plane for the floor, on which the character would move. The layers may be cut in a such manner the inclined floor appears, and the character cannot move out of the floor plane. The whole background would be drawn in an orthogonal viewport to take the appearance of a continuous image. But I don't know if this may be applicable in practice.

Comment: Without knowing more we don't know if it's applicable either. It sounds like you've identified a reasonable starting idea. Have you encountered any problems (either theoretically or via prototyping) that prevent you from using that idea to solve your problem?